# EditText change setError text position

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

So so what im trying to implement has two parts

One im giving my edittext the passwordToggle for which im using 
android.support.design.widget TextInputLayout+TextInputEditText

So this is how my edittext looks like

[image: edittext with passwordToggle]

Part two is i want to add validation and set appropriate error message.
I need the error message to be shown as follows

[image: edittext with custom setError]

My layout code is as follows

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/editTextBold"
    android:id="@+id/input_pwd_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_pwd"
        style="@style/editTextBold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_pwd"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**So what i want to know is**

**1.How do i hide/unhide the password toggle icon in the edittext via code?**

**2.Also how do i make the setError message appear in place of the passwordToggle icon(once i hide it via code)**

Comment: The first part is easy enough - [`TextInputLayout#setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(boolean)). The second is a pretty big change to `TextInputLayout`'s design. It might be easier to just roll your own custom `View`, since it looks like you're now only using `TextInputLayout` for the password toggle. Aside from that, an easy hack might be to switch out the toggle drawable with a drawable that's just your a "Required field" text, as needed

Comment: yea , ended up creating my own custom view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a custom view

[image]

The component can be found here

https://github.com/vnh1991/CustomValidatorEditText

Import the lib project as a module ,

in your layout create a container

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.v2dev.customedittextdemo.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnValidate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llContainer"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Validate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your activity load the component into the container

```
package com.v2dev.customedittextdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.v_sQr_dev.customvalidatoredittext.CustomEdittext;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout llContainer;
    private Button btnValidate;
    private CustomEdittext inputPwd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        llContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
        btnValidate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnValidate);
        inputPwd = new CustomEdittext(llContainer, this);
        inputPwd.setHint("PASSWORD");

        btnValidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(inputPwd.validate()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Input Valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason we cannot just use a `<com.v_sQr_dev.customvalidatoredittext.CustomEdittext>` tag directly in our XML layouts?

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but as my custom view class doesn't extend TextInputEditText , i wont be able to use it directly in the layout.
Code = https://github.com/vnh1991/CustomValidatorEditText/blob/master/customvalidatoredittext2/src/main/java/com/v_sQr_dev/customvalidatoredittext/CustomEdittext.java

Comment: To use your custom view in XML, you must extend `View` or any of its decedents. Doing this should not take too much effort for your custom view. Extending `TextInputEditText` is only required if you want to use your custom view inside of `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: Note that extending `View` will allow you to create custom attributes which can be set in XML. Then you will not need a Context in your custom view class to load any resources. Android will take care of the details for you when you do this correctly.